# Redirect sub domain requests to look like it's from main domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, whmcs

How do I go about doing the following:

I have a main domain at say `http://www.domainname.com`
and a another site at `http://www.domainname.com/billing/`

When loading knowledgebase articles it loads with `http://www.domainname.com/billing/knowledgebase.php`
I want it to load the content but make it look like it's coming from

```
http://www.domainname.com/knowledgebase.php
```

In otherwords anything when I load

> `http://www.domainname.com/knowledgebase.php*`

it should load the content that exists at /billing/knowledgebase.php*

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with the [.htaccess](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) file and the use of `mod_rewrite`, however I know what you're trying to achieve, and from personal experience I'd say to stop while you're ahead, if you want a root based WHMCS install, then delete it all and start again, by installing WHMCS in the root, rather than a sub-directory. Although WHMCS says to install itself in a sub-directory, a lot of people treat it like a CMS, and as such really want it to be the homepage and content manager of the whole site.